# Floating button not working in Pre-lollipop version

Tags: android, android-design-library, floating-action-button, androiddesignsupport

I am using floating action button of Android Design Library in my app which is working fine on lollipop and above versions but getting crashed on pre-lollipop version (4.0-4.2.2) . I am really stuck and unable to figure out the issue .

**Error:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         **android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #396: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton**
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.example.sony.bluedolphintrialapp.DhampureFragment.onCreateView(DhampureFragment.java:18)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
>
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
>
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                          **Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.example.sony.bluedolphintrialapp.DhampureFragment.onCreateView(DhampureFragment.java:18) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          **Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0b0008
>   a=-1 r=0x7f0b0008}**
>
> android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2963)                                                                                         at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:343)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:8                                                                                       at
>   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:77)

**XML with floating action button :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout_signup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sony.bluedolphintrialapp.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@color/backgroud_user"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headertextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="22dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headerlayout"
            android:background="#F2F5F6">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="60dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:stretchColumns="0">


                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:weightSum="1">


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/currentlyEmployed_label"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight=".4"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:text="Channel Partner :"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                        <com.gc.materialdesign.NewMaterials.Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/currentlyEmployed_spinner_id"
                            style="@style/Material.Widget.Spinner.Light"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_weight=".6"
                            app:rd_style="@style/Material.Drawable.Ripple.Wave.Light"
                            app:rd_enable="true"
                            app:rd_delayClick="false"
                            app:spn_labelEnable="true"
                            app:spn_label="Select"
                            app:spn_arrowSwitchMode="true"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            app:spn_arrowAnimDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                            app:spn_arrowInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"/>

                    </TableRow>


                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:weightSum="0.5">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/signup_first_label"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
                            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                                android:id="@+id/addplaces_name"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_person1"
                                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_person1"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                                android:hint="Name"
                                android:inputType="textPersonName" />​
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:weightSum="0.5">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/Adress_first_label"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
                            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
                            ​

                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                                android:id="@+id/adress_name"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_time"
                                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_time"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                                android:hint="Start Time"
                                android:inputType="time|datetime" />​
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    </TableRow>


                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:weightSum="0.5">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/mobileNo_first_label"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
                            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
                            ​

                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                                android:id="@+id/mobileNo_text"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_time"
                                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_time"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                                android:hint="End Time"
                                android:inputType="text|textPostalAddress" />​
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    </TableRow>


                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:weightSum="0.5">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/email_label"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
                            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
                            ​

                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                                android:id="@+id/email_Text"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_time"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                                android:hint="Actual Start Time"
                                android:inputType="text|textPostalAddress" />​
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:weightSum="0.5">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/notes_first_label"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
                            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
                            ​

                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                                android:id="@+id/notes_text"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_time"
                                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                                android:hint="Actual End Time"
                                android:inputType="text|textPostalAddress" />​
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:weightSum="0.5">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/variance_field"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
                            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
                            ​

                            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                                android:id="@+id/variance_text"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_error"
                                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                                android:hint="Variance"
                                android:inputType="text|textPostalAddress" />​
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:weightSum="0.5">

                        <com.dd.CircularProgressButton
                            android:id="@+id/Button_id"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:text="Start"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight=".5"
                            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/personmobile_id"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7sp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            app:cpb_cornerRadius="100dp"
                            app:cpb_selectorComplete="@color/STOPbutton"
                            app:cpb_selectorIdle="@color/backgroud_user"
                            app:cpb_selectorError="@color/sienna"
                            app:cpb_textComplete="STOP"
                            app:cpb_textIdle="START"/>

                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:weightSum="0.5">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/timertext"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="00:00"
                        android:textColor="?colorPrimary"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        />
                    </TableRow>

                </TableLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>
        </com.gc.materialdesign.views.ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fab_iconSize="@dimen/fab_size_mini"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom|right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_format_list_bulleted_white_48dp"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/green_dark"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="25dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: what is your 396 line?

Comment: @justDroid its apparently the floating button tag

Comment: its because of Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList . May be you have given some wrong resource reference there

Comment: The problem was, that the color should be set from own resource `@color/white`, not from android's resource `@android:color/white`. Wierd.

Comment: @Marko : yes it resolved my issue . Thank you so much for the help . Appreciated !!!

Comment: @justDroid yes you right ! the problem was not giving color from my own resource which i able to figure out with marko comment . But thank you so much for the help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with setting the color to `FloatingActionButton`. Changing to the color from our resource (not from Android's), resolves the issue.

So instead of

```
app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
```

it should be

```
app:rippleColor="@color/white"
```